# Java - generic method with bounded types for 3 similar types: String, StringBuilder, StringBuffer

Tags: java, generics

I know it might have no sense at all, but it's just my experiment. There are 3 types (as I know) that supports method `substring()`. I wan't to make a generic method like this:

```
public static <T extends String & StringBuilder & StringBuffer> T substr3(T str) {
        if (str.length() > 3) {
            return (T) str.substring(0, 3);
        }
        return str;
    }
```

It won't compile like this, because you can use as many interfaces as you need, but only one Class as bounded type. This method should work fine for this 3 types: `String`, `StringBuilder`, `StringBuffer` but the questions is: how to set this 3 types as bound types ?

Answer (score 13):

Why not simply `extend CharSequence`?

```
public static <T extends CharSequence> T substr3(T str) {
    if (str.length() > 3) {
        return (T) str.subSequence(0, 3);
    }
    return str;
}
```

**Note**

`CharSequence` doesn't declare any `substring` method, but `subSequence` should provide the identical functionality.

Answer (score -1):

There was also one solution mentioned here:

```
public static <T extends String, StringBuffer, StringBuilder> T substr3(
        T str) {
    if (str.length() > 3) {
        return (T) str.substring(0, 3);
    }
    return str;
}
```

, instead of &.

Comment: That declares 3 type parametes; one named `T`, one named `StringBuffer` and one named `StringBuilder`. Only the first one is used and since its upper bound `String` is `final`, it will always be `String`.